# Dealing with API rate limits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've an app that's set up to make scheduled calls to a number of APIs once a day. This works very nicely but i'm aware that some of the APIs i'm calling (Twitter for example) have a rate limit. As the number of calls i'm making is set to continually grow, can anyone recommend a way to throttle my calls so I can send in bursts of x per hour/minute etc?

I've found the [Glutton Ratelimit](https://github.com/stungeye/glutton_ratelimit) gem, is anyone using this and is it any good? Are there others I should be looking at?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but if you know you're going to consistently grow the number of requests you make then throttling will only cause a queue to grow at the same rate, you need to consider how to deal with a queue that won't ever empty as well.

Comment: Hear what you're saying. I used delayed_job and was hoping to incorporate that in some way. The requests will grow, but I can't see them getting ever growing beyond 10-15k per day.

Comment: Strange how this question got modded up to +4 and [an identical one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309544/how-to-make-concurrent-http-request-in-ruby-at-the-fastest-rate-possible-to-not) got modded down to -3 and closed. I guess timing is everything

Comment: Why not keep a cache, mapping a token to the last time it's been used, as well as the # of time its been used in the past X minutes. Update this cache as you make a call and/or get the X-rate limit response back.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using some kind of background worker to perform your API calls, you could reschedule the task to be reperformed in the next time slot, when the rate limits have been reset.

```
class TwitterWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(status_id)
    status = Twitter.status(status_id)
    # ...

  rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests
    # Reschedule the query to be performed in the next time slot
    TwitterWorker.perform_in(15.minutes, status_id)
  end
end
```

No scientific solution though, there's e.g. the risk that a query might be rescheduled each time if you try to perform much more API calls in a day than the rate limit allows for. But until then, something easy might do the trick!

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'm using delayed_job to perform background jobs. I'll look into this further, thanks for your advice.

Comment: This is a really nice, simple idea.  I'm actually naming the rescued exception `e` and doing `perform_id(e.rate_limit.reset_in, ...)` so that it retries as soon as there is quota

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to buy proxies which allow you to send request with different IP addresses

Use standard http lib http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-Proxy

I am not sure that you will not be blocked but maybe it is worth to try. Randomly choosen IP should increase your limits

Comment: This technique might work for unauthenticated APIs. However, when you work with the Twitter REST API 1.1, all your requests need to be authenticated and are thus directly tied to you, no matter which IP the request comes from. Good thinking, though!

Comment: Yes exactly. Proxies will help for per-ip rate limits like google maps, but not for per-account limits like I imagine twitter has.

Comment: Interesting approach and could prove useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're making concurrent requests there's not much to it.

- Figure out how much delay you need per request
- Check the time before the request, subtract from the time after the
  request and `sleep` the rest.

With concurrent requests you can be more accurate, [I once blogged about that here](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/ruby-rate-limiting-concurrent-downloads.html)

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at your blog.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to mention something in case it helps others with the same question.

If the work can be queued to jobs using resque, then you could use the gem I've just released which pauses a queue when you hit a rate_limit - and unpauses it some time later.

https://github.com/pavoni/resque-rate_limited_queue