# configure sidekiq to work only two requests per second

Tags: api, shopify, sidekiq

I'm sending stockupdates to the shopify-api. The requests are queued with sidekiq. Shopify allows 2 requests per second. I can't find a way to configure sidekiq to work only 2 scheduled jobs per second.

Comment: You seem confused. API LImits have nothing to do with running background jobs. You run a background job because it takes a long time, and involves many many API requests. If you need to work out how to limit your API requests, that has everything to do with your code IN the background job, and nothing to do with Sidekiq.

Comment: The official rate limiting API for Sidekiq is here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting

Comment: I'm not confused, it's pretty easy, I schedule three jobs in the same second, one fails because two are allowed. Should be handled by the background-job-layer in my opinion

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking to do is to slow down the number of requests that your web application makes to an API. Aka "Rate Limiting".

Sidekiq Enterprise provides a [rate limiting API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting) that gives you three options for rate limiting, two of which could likely raise an exception after the rate limit has been exceeded.

> Rate limiters do **not** slow down Sidekiq's job processing. If you push
>   1000 jobs to Redis, Sidekiq will run those jobs as fast as possible
>   which may cause many of those jobs to fail with an OverLimit error.

Therefore

> If you want to trickle jobs into Sidekiq slowly, the only way to do
>   that is with manual scheduling.

With that said, now your options are twofold: You can either slow down redis or you can implement the rate limiting feature yourself within the context of your web application.

As an example from the same documentation page:

> Here's how you can schedule 1 job per second to ensure that Sidekiq
>   doesn't run all jobs immediately:

```
1000.times do |index|
  SomeWorker.perform_in(index, some_args)
end
```

And you probably don't want to have to slow down redis because

> Rate limiting is unusually hard on Redis for a Sidekiq feature

Instead, you could `rescue` the exception that would be thrown by the API you're working with similarly to the following answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645482/dealing-with-api-rate-limits):

```
class TwitterWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(status_id)
    status = Twitter.status(status_id)
    # ...

  rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests
    # Reschedule the query to be performed in the next time slot
    TwitterWorker.perform_in(15.minutes, status_id)
  end
end
```

In conclusion, unless you want to pay for Sidekiq Enterprise and implement your solution around it or deal with redis directly, I recommend that you rescue the exception creating a loop with a retry feature (`perform_in`) only until you've exceeded the API's requests limit, as in the example above.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea of adding a class variable to my worker so I could store an array with timestamp in seconds of the last scheduled job and a number o jobs for this second. When I schedule a job I look at the array for the last scheduled second and the number and increment the seconds and jobs if there are two for a future second and schedule my job on the next second.